# Issue with recoding objects to numerical values

Tags: python, encoding

I am extremely new to this so bare with me please.

I'm following this https://pbpython.com/categorical-encoding.html to simply replace the categorical variables within my data with numerical ones. i.e. Gender = M/F, I need it to be M=1 F=2 instead otherwise I can't apply preprocessing steps to my data properly.

I have used this

```
Object_Replace = {"CODE_GENDER": {"M": 1, "F": 2}}
obj_df = obj_df.replace(Object_Replace)
obj_df.head()
```

but the output is still showing M/F instead of 1 and 2.. WHY?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I can't but here is a screenshot my problem https://imgur.com/a/X2LbdSG